# How to run java while loop until file exists in a particular directory?

Tags: java

I would like to run the while loop until the file is available in a particular directory.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/MediaIntegTests/src"
                + "/mediaServiceTests"
                + "/Resources/RawImages/"
                + "mediaResponses/InputJson/");
        while (path.iterator().hasNext()){
            String fileName = String.valueOf(path.getFileName());
            imageEncoder(path+ fileName);
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/gomathis/Documents/res/Media/mediaIntegTests/src/mediaServiceTests/Resources/RawImages/mediaPVResponses/InputJsonInputJson (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:103)
    at com.example.mediaservice.TestUtils.CommonTestUtils.imageEncoder(CommonTestUtils.java:80)
    at com.example.mediaservice.TestUtils.CommonTestUtils.main(CommonTestUtils.java:46)
```

Comment: You could use a test like `isRegularFile`, but it'd be much more efficient to use a `WatchService`

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: use a `WatchService`, see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html): "... For example a file manager may use a watch service to monitor a directory for changes so that it can update its display of the list of files when files are created or deleted. ..."

Comment: Will watchservice helps me to execute the test cases even when the file is not changed.

Comment: The question isn't very clear as the answer you added (scan files in a dir) doesn't seem to match what you asked for (wait until files added to a dir). Anyway it looks like you have resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputJsonInputJson -> InputJson/InputJson

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fileLst = new ArrayList<String> ();
        
        scanDir("c:/cleardir", fileLst);
        
        for(String fullPath : fileLst) {
            System.out.println(fullPath);
        }       
    }   
    
    
    public static void scanDir(String folderPath, List<String> fileLst) {
        File[] files = new File(folderPath).listFiles();
        
        for(File f : files) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                scanDir(f.getAbsolutePath(), fileLst);
            } else {
                fileLst.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided by @ ᄆᄂᄋᄅᄆᄂᄋᆱᄂᄋᄅ.
I've re-written as shown below:

```
Path filepath = Paths.get("/Resources/RawImages/"
                + "mediaResponses/InputJson/");
        File[] filePath = new File("/Resources/RawImages/"
                + "mediaResponses/InputJson/").listFiles();
        assert filePath != null;
        for (File eachFile: filePath){
            if(eachFile.isFile()){
                String fileName = eachFile.getName();
                imageEncoder(filepath +"/" +fileName);
```